# How can I test bench a VHDL 24 hour Clock?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm having a bit of problem when trying to test bench my VHDL. 
I'm using a fpga Baysis 2 to run my code, and it is working pretty well on the hardware, but when I use the program Isim to simulate my code, it doesn't show any behavior for my out pins, only the letter U.

I'm looking through the internet and couldn't find a solution, can someone help me on this one?

Here follows the last part of my code (probably the one with the something wrong). Before that the code simply had a process to divide the clock to measure 1 second another to divide in 1/200 of a second to quickly turn on and off the led's on the fpga's display, and counted the seconds to make the 24 hour clock work, of course.

```
    contador: process(clk200)

variable flag : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
-- ledplex is the mux that controls which display should be on
-- Segm is the 7 segments display 
-- mu md hu hd are the signals with the time information
begin

if(clk200'event and clk200='1') then
     if (flag = "00") then

        ledplex <= "1110";

            case mu is 
                when 0 => segm <= "1000000";
                when 1 => segm <= "1111001";
                when 2 => segm <= "0100100";
                when 3 => segm <= "0110000";
                when 4 => segm <= "0011001";
                when 5 => segm <= "0010010";
                when 6 => segm <= "0000011";
                when 7 => segm <= "1111000";
                when 8 => segm <= "0000000";
                when 9 => segm <= "0011000";
                when others => segm <= "1111111";   
            end case;
        flag := "01";

    elsif (flag = "01") then

        ledplex <= "1101";

            case md is 
                when 0 => segm <= "1000000";
                when 1 => segm <= "1111001";
                when 2 => segm <= "0100100";
                when 3 => segm <= "0110000";
                when 4 => segm <= "0011001";
                when 5 => segm <= "0010010";
                when others => segm <= "1111111";           
            end case;
    flag := "10";

    elsif (flag = "10") then
        ledplex <= "1011";

            case hu is 
                when 0 => segm <= "1000000";
                when 1 => segm <= "1111001";
                when 2 => segm <= "0100100";
                when 3 => segm <= "0110000";
                when 4 => segm <= "0011001";
                when 5 => segm <= "0010010";
                when 6 => segm <= "0000011";
                when 7 => segm <= "1111000";
                when 8 => segm <= "0000000";
                when 9 => segm <= "0011000";
                when others => segm <= "1111111";   
            end case;
        flag := "11";

    elsif (flag = "11") then
        ledplex <= "0111";

            case hd is 
                when 0 => segm <= "1000000";
                when 1 => segm <= "1111001";
                when 2 => segm <= "0100100";
                when others => segm <= "1111111";           
            end case;
    flag := "00";

    end if;
end if;
end process contador;
```

and here follows the test bench
    LIBRARY ieee;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

```
 ENTITY t_b IS
 END t_b;

   ARCHITECTURE behavior OF t_b IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT hora
   PORT(
     clk25m : IN  std_logic;
     segm : OUT  std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
     ledplex : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        x : out std_logic
    );
   END COMPONENT;

    signal  clk_tb : std_logic := '0';
    signal  segm_tb : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal   ledplex_tb : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal x_tb : std_logic;

    BEGIN

    CUT: hora port map(  clk25m => clk_tb,
                                segm => segm_tb,
                                ledplex => ledplex_tb,
                                x => x_tb);


    Test_Vector: process
    begin
    clk_tb <= '1';
    wait for 40 ns;
    clk_tb <= '0';
    wait for 40 ns;
    end process;

    END behavior;
```

Comment: I can see you don't want to overwhelm people with lots of code, but instead of getting rid of the bits that stop it compiling, how about getting rid of the bits that are irrelevant to your problem? That way, you present us with some code that compiles and runs so we can easily reproduce your problem without giving too much code. This is called an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's another advantage to creating an MCVE, too: in creating one, it is quite likely that the questioner find the problem themself and so learns more than they would by just reading someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize your variable `flag`. Without this your variable may be undefined, hence `U`. Use the following:

```
variable flag : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := "00"; -- initialize variable
```